# SQL new column from existing column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two columns:

```
column1        column2
1              ID1_1
2              ID2_2
3              ID3
```

I want to add a third column based on the value of the second column. If the value contain an underscore, I want to split the value by underscore and use the first part. If the value contains no underscore, I just want to insert the same value:

```
column1        column2      column3
1              ID1_1        ID1
2              ID2_2        ID2
3              ID3          ID3
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various options; here are a few of them:

- one (`col3_a`) uses regular expressions and fetches the first *word* (that's why `_` is replaced by `!`)
- another (`col3_b`) uses case expression which searches for `_`; if it exists, take substring that precedes it. Otherwise, take the string itself
- or, regular expression again - take alphanumerics at the beginning of the string (`col3_c`)

---

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 1, 'ID1_1' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'ID2_2' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'ID3'   from dual
  5    )
  6  select col1, col2,
  7    regexp_substr(replace(col2, '_', '!'), '\w+') col3_a,
  8    --
  9    case when instr(col2, '_') > 0 then substr(col2, 1, instr(col2, '_') - 1)
 10         else col2
 11    end col3_b,
 12    --
 13    regexp_substr(col2, '^[[:alnum:]]+') col3_c
 14  from test;

      COL1 COL2  COL3_A COL3_B COL3_C
---------- ----- ------ ------ ------
         1 ID1_1 ID1    ID1    ID1
         2 ID2_2 ID2    ID2    ID2
         3 ID3   ID3    ID3    ID3

SQL>
```

---

If you want to add a new column to the table, then `alter` it and update newly added column's value.

```
SQL> select * from test;

      COL1 COL2
---------- -----
         1 ID1_1
         2 ID2_2
         3 ID3

SQL> alter table test add col3 varchar2(10);

Table altered.

SQL> update test set
  2    col3 = case when instr(col2, '_') > 0 then substr(col2, 1, instr(col2, '_') - 1)
  3                else col2
  4           end;

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test;

      COL1 COL2  COL3
---------- ----- ----------
         1 ID1_1 ID1
         2 ID2_2 ID2
         3 ID3   ID3

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I used the second version in order to specify the occurrence of the underscore.

Comment: One more question how to add the new column permanent in the table?

Comment: Alter the table; have a look at edited answer which shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If available to you, the [generated column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) feature can come in handy :

```sql
alter table mytable 
    add column3 as (regexp_substr(column2, '^[^_]+', 1));
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c3438)

Comment: From my point of view, that's invalid ALTER TABLE syntax for Oracle (COLUMN should be removed). TEXT is invalid datatype in Oracle. SPLIT_PART function doesn't exist in Oracle. Which database do you use?

Comment: @Littlefoot Oops! that would be PostGreSQL dialect, which is more different from Oracle than I thought. Rewrote the snippet and added a fiddle. Thank you!